# How do I use Philips Hue "ddx" and "stable/not stable" operators

Tags: philips-hue

I'm trying to expand the actions of a Philips Hue Tap Switch by recognising multiple slow and fast presses. Philips API mentions the "ddx" and "stable" operators but has no detail. Does anyone know where they are fully spec'd?

Comment: Check out the tag wiki. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/philips-hue/info

Answer (score 2):

stable/not stable evaluate if a value has/has not changed for a given time. It will not trigger a rule change on it's own, only in conjunction with other conditions. Syntax is the same as ddx.

The following condition would evaluate true if motion was detected after a period of 30 minutes following no motion detection.

"address":"/sensors/1/state/presence","operator":"eq", "value":"true",
"address":"/sensors/1/state/presence","operator":"stable", "value":"PT00:30:00"

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the rules set up by the Philips app, I found "Go to sleep fade" which uses "ddx" to trigger an action after a 1 minute interval:
                "address": "/sensors/4/state/flag",
                "operator": "ddx",
                "value": "PT00:01:00"
Still looking for usage of "stable/not stable".